# Play more than one sound in the iPad browser

Tags: ios, html, safari

I've been trying to play more than one sound simultaneously in the iPad browser, and it appears that it isn't possible using raw `<audio>` tags. Starting one `<audio>` source will always pause any other playing `<audio>` sources, whether they were initiated via user tap on the controls, or with the `.play()` method.

Are there any other approaches that might work for multiple simultaneous sounds (QuickTime, `<embed>`, etc.)?

Comment: I believe you can use the HTML5 audio APIs, but I don't know much at all about them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Kevin. I've already tried using multiple `<audio>` tags and the `.play()` method, but they always pause existing playing sounds before starting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now that iOS 6 is available, WebAudio is the way to go. This is still not possible in iOS 5.

Answer (score 1):

Apple have taken a design decision that doesn't allow you to play more than one audio file at a time. It's an intended limitation of the device I'm afraid.

Comment: What I said at the time was true. Changing the answer rather than commenting here as an ammendment doesn't say much for you.